# Rounding to nearest or up in SQLite

Tags: sqlite, floating-point, rounding

I've got an existing calculation (in SQL) which contains several formulas involving rounding. Now I've got to make sure that the rounding uses the **half up** [tie-breaking alorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Tie-breaking).

It appears that by default, SQLite's [`round`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#round) function uses the **half to even** algorithm.

Is there a simple way to change that to **half up**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The built-in `round` function rounds towards negative infinity.

There is no simply way to do half-to-even directly in SQL.

You'd have to [install your own](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/create_function.html) custom rounding function, or modify the SQLite source code:

```c
if( n==0 && r>=0 && r<LARGEST_INT64-1 ){
  r = (double)((sqlite_int64)(r+0.5));
}else if( n==0 && r<0 && (-r)<LARGEST_INT64-1 ){
  r = -(double)((sqlite_int64)((-r)+0.5));
}else{
  zBuf = sqlite3_mprintf("%.*f",n,r);
  sqlite3AtoF(zBuf, &r, sqlite3Strlen30(zBuf), SQLITE_UTF8);
}
```

Comment: I ended up [redefining](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/create_function.html) the built-in `round` function with one of my own, which was surprisingly easy. Thanks for the pointer!

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and the following sql seemed to work:

select ceiling(1.0* your_number_column / round_to_number) * round_to_number from your_table

-- note 1.0 * is needed to ensures it becomes a decimal

for example, if 'round_to_number' is the nearest 500:

select ceiling(1.0 * your_number_column / 500) * 500 from your_table  -

0 stays 0,
1 becomes 500,
501 becomes 1000,
and so on...